# Error Traced[line: 42] Le contenu des éléments doit inclure un balisage ou des caractères au format correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsf

i have a jquery code in html thats working well :

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Modal form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <style>
    body { font-size: 62.5%; }
    label, input { display:block; }
    input.text { margin-bottom:12px; width:95%; padding: .4em; }
    fieldset { padding:0; border:0; margin-top:25px; }
    h1 { font-size: 1.2em; margin: .6em 0; }
    div#users-contain { width: 350px; margin: 20px 0; }
    div#users-contain table { margin: 1em 0; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }
    div#users-contain table td, div#users-contain table th { border: 1px solid #eee; padding: .6em 10px; text-align: left; }
    .ui-dialog .ui-state-error { padding: .3em; }
    .validateTips { border: 1px solid transparent; padding: 0.3em; }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var name = $( "#name" ),
      email = $( "#email" ),
      password = $( "#password" ),
      allFields = $( [] ).add( name ).add( email ).add( password ),
      tips = $( ".validateTips" );

    function updateTips( t ) {
      tips
        .text( t )
        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
      setTimeout(function() {
        tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
      }, 500 );
    }

    function checkLength( o, n, min, max ) {
      if ( o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( "Length of " + n + " must be between " +
          min + " and " + max + "." );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

    function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
      if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( n );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 300,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Create an account": function() {
          var bValid = true;
          allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

          bValid = bValid && checkLength( name, "username", 3, 16 );
          bValid = bValid && checkLength( email, "email", 6, 80 );
          bValid = bValid && checkLength( password, "password", 5, 16 );

          bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( name, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_])+$/i, "Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, begin with a letter." );
          // From jquery.validate.js (by joern), contributed by Scott Gonzalez: http://projects.scottsplayground.com/email_address_validation/
          bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( email, /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i, "eg. ui@jquery.com" );
          bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( password, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Password field only allow : a-z 0-9" );

          if ( bValid ) {
            $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
              "<td>" + name.val() + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + email.val() + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + password.val() + "</td>" +
            "</tr>" );
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
          }
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
      }
    });

    $( "#create-user" )
      .button()
      .click(function() {
        $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
      });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
  <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

  <form>
  <fieldset>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
  </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>


<div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
  <h1>Existing Users:</h1>
  <table id="users" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
    <thead>
      <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Password</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John Doe</td>
        <td>john.doe@example.com</td>
        <td>johndoe1</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<button id="create-user">Create new user</button>


</body>
</html>
```

But when i move this code to JSF didnt work thats the code :

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Modal form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <style>
    body { font-size: 62.5%; }
    label, input { display:block; }
    input.text { margin-bottom:12px; width:95%; padding: .4em; }
    fieldset { padding:0; border:0; margin-top:25px; }
    h1 { font-size: 1.2em; margin: .6em 0; }
    div#users-contain { width: 350px; margin: 20px 0; }
    div#users-contain table { margin: 1em 0; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }
    div#users-contain table td, div#users-contain table th { border: 1px solid #eee; padding: .6em 10px; text-align: left; }
    .ui-dialog .ui-state-error { padding: .3em; }
    .validateTips { border: 1px solid transparent; padding: 0.3em; }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var name = $( "#name" ),
      email = $( "#email" ),
      password = $( "#password" ),
      allFields = $( [] ).add( name ).add( email ).add( password ),
      tips = $( ".validateTips" );

    function updateTips( t ) {
      tips
        .text( t )
        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
      setTimeout(function() {
        tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
      }, 500 );
    }

    function checkLength( o, n, min, max ) {
      if ( o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( "Length of " + n + " must be between " +
          min + " and " + max + "." );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

    function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
      if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( n );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 300,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Create an account": function() {
          var bValid = true;
          allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

          bValid = bValid && checkLength( name, "username", 3, 16 );
          bValid = bValid && checkLength( email, "email", 6, 80 );
          bValid = bValid && checkLength( password, "password", 5, 16 );

          bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( name, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_])+$/i, "Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, begin with a letter." );
          // From jquery.validate.js (by joern), contributed by Scott Gonzalez: http://projects.scottsplayground.com/email_address_validation/
          bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( email, /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i, "eg. ui@jquery.com" );
          bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( password, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Password field only allow : a-z 0-9" );

          if ( bValid ) {
            $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
              "<td>" + name.val() + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + email.val() + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + password.val() + "</td>" +
            "</tr>" );
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
          }
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
      }
    });

    $( "#create-user" )
      .button()
      .click(function() {
        $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
      });
  });
  </script>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>

<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
  <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

  <form>
  <fieldset>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
  </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>


<div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
  <h1>Existing Users:</h1>
  <table id="users" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
    <thead>
      <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Password</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John Doe</td>
        <td>john.doe@example.com</td>
        <td>johndoe1</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<button id="create-user">Create new user</button>


    </h:body>
</html>
```

i have this error Error Traced[line: 42] Le contenu des éléments doit inclure un balisage ou des caractères au format correct

> :[line: 42] >       if ( o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min
>   )

*HTML :*

[image]

*XHTML :*

[image]

Comment: JSF assumes XML, right? Try to replace all the `<` with `&#60;` and all the `&` with `&#38;` and see if that helps.

Comment: Please fix your development environment to emit error messages in English. Otherwise you will never find the right answers here on Stack Overflow when you copypaste the exact error message into the Search box or even into Google.

Comment: i added to my code `<![CDATA[  ]]>` now i have no errors but i have the same screen that i showed for XHTML with no effect when clicking to create new user.

Comment: its working now i added `<![CDATA[ ]]>` in place of `//<![CDATA[  my js code here //]]>`

Comment: I have had the same issue. The problem was I had an Xml declaration like this one on top of my document.

I also had to delete the xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml attribute in my html tag.

Where comes that issue from ? When you create an html file with Netbeans, you need to choose the file extension type. Netbeans 8 have 2 differents kind of so called "create Html file" . The first one is a classic html 5 file. And the second seems to be an Xml file . . . even if you are clicking on "creating an html file".

Answer (score 3):

Since you are will be using XHTML in JSF you have to replace `&` with `&amp;` , `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`.
So I have made changes in your code, Replace the respective functions.

```
function checkLength( o, n, min, max ) {
          if ( o.val().length &gt; max || o.val().length &lt; min ) {
            o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
            updateTips( "Length of " + n + " must be between " +
              min + " and " + max + "." );
            return false;
          } else {
            return true;
          }
        }
```

**and**

```
 "Create an account": function() {
          var bValid = true;
          allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

          bValid = bValid &amp;&amp; checkLength( name, "username", 3, 16 );
          bValid = bValid &amp;&amp; checkLength( email, "email", 6, 80 );
          bValid = bValid &amp;&amp; checkLength( password, "password", 5, 16 );

          bValid = bValid &amp;&amp; checkRegexp( name, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_])+$/i, "Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, begin with a letter." );
          // From jquery.validate.js (by joern), contributed by Scott Gonzalez: http://projects.scottsplayground.com/email_address_validation/
          bValid = bValid &amp;&amp; checkRegexp( email, /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&amp;'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&amp;'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i, "eg. ui@jquery.com" );
          bValid = bValid &amp;&amp; checkRegexp( password, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Password field only allow : a-z 0-9" );
```

Here is the complete altered code:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Modal form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <style>
    body { font-size: 62.5%; }
    label, input { display:block; }
    input.text { margin-bottom:12px; width:95%; padding: .4em; }
    fieldset { padding:0; border:0; margin-top:25px; }
    h1 { font-size: 1.2em; margin: .6em 0; }
    div#users-contain { width: 350px; margin: 20px 0; }
    div#users-contain table { margin: 1em 0; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }
    div#users-contain table td, div#users-contain table th { border: 1px solid #eee; padding: .6em 10px; text-align: left; }
    .ui-dialog .ui-state-error { padding: .3em; }
    .validateTips { border: 1px solid transparent; padding: 0.3em; }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var name = $( "#name" ),
      email = $( "#email" ),
      password = $( "#password" ),
      allFields = $( [] ).add( name ).add( email ).add( password ),
      tips = $( ".validateTips" );

    function updateTips( t ) {
      tips
        .text( t )
        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
      setTimeout(function() {
        tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
      }, 500 );
    }

    function checkLength( o, n, min, max ) {
      if ( o.val().length &gt; max || o.val().length &lt; min ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( "Length of " + n + " must be between " +
          min + " and " + max + "." );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

    function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
      if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( n );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 300,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Create an account": function() {
          var bValid = true;
          allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

          bValid = bValid &amp;&amp; checkLength( name, "username", 3, 16 );
          bValid = bValid &amp;&amp; checkLength( email, "email", 6, 80 );
          bValid = bValid &amp;&amp; checkLength( password, "password", 5, 16 );

          bValid = bValid &amp;&amp; checkRegexp( name, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_])+$/i, "Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, begin with a letter." );
          // From jquery.validate.js (by joern), contributed by Scott Gonzalez: http://projects.scottsplayground.com/email_address_validation/
          bValid = bValid &amp;&amp; checkRegexp( email, /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&amp;'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&amp;'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i, "eg. ui@jquery.com" );
          bValid = bValid &amp;&amp; checkRegexp( password, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Password field only allow : a-z 0-9" );

          if ( bValid ) {
            $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
              "<td>" + name.val() + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + email.val() + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + password.val() + "</td>" +
            "</tr>" );
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
          }
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
      }
    });

    $( "#create-user" )
      .button()
      .click(function() {
        $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
      });
  });
  </script>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>

<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
  <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

  <form>
  <fieldset>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
  </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>


<div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
  <h1>Existing Users:</h1>
  <table id="users" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
    <thead>
      <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Password</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John Doe</td>
        <td>john.doe@example.com</td>
        <td>johndoe1</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<button id="create-user">Create new user</button>


    </h:body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**
One more alternative is to use External Javascript.
Keep your javascript in separate file say: *script.js* and access it using following tag:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"/>
```

This techniques is working fine in my PC now.

Comment: i used your code but i still have same problem ,see my update what i have in HTML and what i have in XHTML. the button "create new user" in xhtml didnt show the modal form .

Comment: i already tryed this methode before posting this topic the difference is i dont have an error but non effect when click on my button and with bad display of the form that is showen in the first page .